# Converting a List<String> to an Array[] and binding to ListView in android

Tags: android

This is my code

```
ListView listQuestions = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,AllQuestions.toArray(new String[AllQuestions.size()]));
listQuestions.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

it keeps throwing error

this is the error from logcat

Question cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[]

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: What is the error? Please post logcat error trace.

Comment: Where's your logcat and the declaration of Array[] AllQuestions?

Comment: Why you want to convert List to Array because you can also pass List to ArrayAdapter

Comment: The list is coming from the database

Comment: how can i pass the list to array adapter ?

Comment: Question cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[] is the error

Comment: @sam bains Question cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[]

Answer (score 0):

Pass **List** to **Array Adapter**:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Item 1");
list.add("Item 2");
list.add("Item 3");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```